# Como puedo hacer que se repita varias veces una linea de código?

Tags: python

Quiero que se repita un número de segundos determinado o, que no pare de repetirse

```
import pyautogui


a = "Autoclicker"
b = "Auto press buttom"
c = "Exit"


choices = {a: 'Autoclicker', b: 'Auto press buttom', c: 'exit'}

answer = pyautogui.confirm('Choose one.' , buttons=list(choices))

if answer == a:
   print("Has seleccionado Autoclicker")
   pyautogui.alert(text=choices[answer], button='OK')
   pyautogui.click()
```

Quiero que la ultima linea "pyautogui.click()" se repita un número de segundos determinado o en su defecto que no se pare de repetir, en la página de pyautogui no encontré ninguna función que haga eso

Comment: ¿Y si lo metes en un bucle? Yo pondría también un `time.sleep()` en el mismo bucle para que espere un tiempo dado entre un click y el siguiente.

Comment: Exacto, puedes usar un bucle, es algo básico en programación y hay muchos tutoriales sobre eso. Te dejo un enlace qué explica sobre bucles.  
 http://www.mclibre.org/consultar/python/lecciones/python-for.html

Comment: Muchas gracias a los dos, soy nuevo en esto y siento mucho si mis preguntas son básicas.